# $_POST sometimes empty when sending mail

Tags: javascript, php, forms, post

I have a contact form that emails myself the contact info submitted, but sometimes I get an empty `$_POST` array, which results in me receiving an empty email. I used a validator JavaScript file to ensure that the fields entered are not empty and the only way I'm receiving an empty email is for `$_POST` to be empty. I included my code that includes the form, JavaScript file, and PHP file.

My form:

```
        <div class="row contact-wrap"> 
            <div id="error-message" style="display: none;" ><p>ERROR</p></div>
            <form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php" data-toggle="validator" role="form">
                <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputname" class="control-label">NAME</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" id="inputname" class="form-control" data-error="Name required!" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputemail" class="control-label">EMAIL</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="inputemail" class="form-control" data-error="Email required!" required>
                    </div>                     
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputsubject" class="control-label">SUBJECT</label>
                        <input type="text" name="subject" id="inputsubject" class="form-control" data-error="Subject required!" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputmessage" class="control-label">MESSAGE</label>
                        <textarea name="message" id="inputmessage" class="form-control" rows="8" data-error="Message required!" required></textarea>
                    </div>                        
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" required="required">SUBMIT</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form> 
        </div>

    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="js/validator.min.js"></script>
```

main.js JavaScript file to validate my fields:

```
    jQuery(function($) {'use strict',
    var form = $('#main-contact-form')
    var message = $('#error-message')
    form.validator().on('submit', function (e) {
      if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        message.fadeIn();
      } else {

        e.preventDefault();  
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            beforeSend: function(){
                form.prepend(
                    message
                        .html('<p>Sending...</p>')
                        .fadeIn()
                );
            }
        }).done(function(data){
           message.html('<p>' + data.message + '</p>').delay(2000).fadeOut();
           form.delay(2000).fadeOut();
           console.log("DONE");
        });
      }
    })
});
```

sendmail.php file I'm using to send myself the form data:

```
<?php

// configure
$from = $_POST['email'];
$sendTo = 'my@email.com';
$fields = array('name' => 'Name', 'email' => 'Email', 'subject' => 'Subject', 'message' => 'Message');

try
{
    $emailText = "\n=============================\n";

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
        }
    }

    mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, "From: " . $from);

    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
}
else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

Comment: Are you sending these messages, or do they seem to be happening randomly?

Comment: I randomly get empty messages, which means that $_POST is empty.

Comment: Try to also validate the message with PHP. It is possible for the user to remove the validation you do or bypass it. PHP will allow you to catch it.

Comment: validation on the client side is a great way to improve user experience but it is not a substitute for server side validation. both sides should always validate.

Comment: I quite sure the issue isn't the user not entering any data since even if the fields are empty, I would still get something in the email I receive. The issue is $_POST being empty.

Comment: * used a validator js file to ensure that the fields entered are not empty and the only way I'm receiving...* - Javascript is NOT a reliable validation method.  You **must** also validate server side.  It's absolutely trivial for someone to work around the javascript.

Comment: Thanks, will also add server side validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no check in `sendmail.php` that states, *if these conditions are met, send the email* or *if these conditions are not met, don't send the email*.  Currently, the email is always sent.

Somebody or something (spider, crawler, Googlebot, etc...) is accessing `sendmail.php` directly without submitting the form.  Check for submit in `sendmail.php`:

```
if(!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    die("Scumbag, use the form!");
}
```

Or check each submitted field, as it is easy for someone to post `submit` or other fields directly to your script as well.

For something a little more robust, see [Cross-Site Request Forgeries](http://shiflett.org/articles/cross-site-request-forgeries), which will help with this as well.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense that something is accessing sendmail.php directly without submitting the form. I'll add server side validation and only send the email if the required fields are present.